# "Restore session" in gVim like in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, restore, gvim, browser-tabs

I left some files opened in gVim, and hibernated my machine.

Unfortunately, there was some error, and I lost my gVim session.

Is it possible to do like modern browsers nowadays (like Firefox), that after "crashing" (not exiting in normal ways), showing a "Restore last session" dialog in my gVim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to run `:mksession` periodically. Vim does not support timers as far as I know, but you could associate `:mksession` to a `:autocmd` event such as `BufNewFile`.

A possible event to use in these cases is `VimLeavePre`, e.g.:

```
autocmd VimLeavePre * mksession! .vim.sess
```

Comment: Do you mean associating :mksession each time I use :w for example?

Comment: just as a hint (because :mksession is correct): http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2010

Comment: yep that's what I meant

Comment: I did a different solution, but using a similar concept that you suggested: autocmd VimLeavePre * mksession! .vim.sess
 I think it would be a good idea to you to edit your answer and add the VimLeavePre approach! http://jaredforsyth.com/blog/2010/apr/9/vim-crash-recovery/

Comment: Enabling just that autocmd and adding -S to the gVim startup command will enable automatic session management! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

If you want another hint, or something that is more user friendly and asks you at start up if you want to load the session, you could give a try to http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3150 . I use it and it works quite well for me. You can have multiple sessions and it is very user friendly. You can SaveSession, OpenSession, DeleteSession and the files are stored in .vim/sessions so that you can use still mksession if you want.

Comment: I'm with too many plugins already, I started using builtin functions for some stuff... but thanks for the suggestion!